# How to execute an AQL query with Java API?

Tags: java, arangodb

I have a collection named `docCollection` and I want to perform a normal AQL query on for example:

```
FOR id IN docCollection FILTER id.center == "Germany" RETURN id
```

I have tried to use the example as stated here:

https://github.com/arangodb/docs/blob/2f0a96c23630719e09f1b7af6aaf106c44332555/drivers/java-examples-xml-data.md

But it didn't worked for me and it showed me

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Can you locate the stack trace where in the source this occured?

Comment: `CursorResult<BaseDocument> rs = driver.executeAqlQuery(query, null, null, BaseDocument.class);`  -- here

Comment: you did see that the example you pasted uses `executeAqlQueryRaw` and not `executeAqlQuery`?

Comment: whats the difference ?

Comment: And also I have tried both ways

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally you have to use *driver.executeDocumentQuery(...)* for document queries.

To illustrate the differences between *driver.executeDocumentQuery(...)* and *driver.executeAqlQuery(...)* I added an [example](https://gist.github.com/bd68b523647548e5fb36d27c29561cfe).

Download the ArangoDB java driver on github and compile it with maven:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests=true -Dgpg.skip=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -B
```

Maven creates the standalone driver JAR file (arangodb-java-driver-X.X.X-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar) containing all dependencies in the target directory.

Fetch the example code:

```
 wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/bd68b523647548e5fb36d27c29561cfe/raw/f2922d431b9f1e5a3f3239e9024cf342536f55f7/AqlExample.java
```

Compile the example code:

```
 javac -classpath arangodb-java-driver-X.X.X-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar AqlExample.java
```

Start the ArangoDB without authentication on the default port and run the example code:

```
 java -classpath arangodb-java-driver-X.X.X-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar:. AqlExample
```